# Start Relay Chain error "substrate : command no found"

Tags: substrate

I am trying to do a substrate tutorial, "Start your relay chain".
(https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/)

Here, I copied the code and run it to start the alice validator.

```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain <path to spec json> \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

"path to spec json" - What should I replace this?
I tried to build a chain spec file like this.

```
substrate build-spec > myCustomSpec.json
```

Error is here, "**substrate : command no found**"
What's the problem? Anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Polkadot is used to create the chain spec as described in the tutorial. You don't have substrate installed, and that would be incorrect to use anyway.

See the sections on raw and plain chain spec generation.